# Connect to EC2 VPC through VPN without configuring router or using third party client

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC running two EC2 instances. I'd like to be able to connect to this virtual network through VPN, from any device, without having to configure the router and without having to install any third party software (for example, on Windows I'd like to use the standard "Connect to a network" > "Connect VPN connection").

Setting up the VPN using the standard EC2 VPN connection with a Virtual Private Gateway requires me to also set up a Customer Gateway, which involves configuring the router and therefore doesn't seem possible in my case. Using OpenVPN seems to require the OpenVPN client to be installed on the connecting machines, which is also not possible in my case. Is there any solution or am I out of luck?

Edit: I'm restricted to using a Windows-based VPN server. I found a good guide for setting this up, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide shows how to do it for Windows Server 2012 http://www.sysads.co.uk/2013/02/setup-windows-server-2012-vpn-part1/

Answer (score 2):

You can setup an PPTP server that works with Windows out the box (as a client). For example you can setup the server on Ubuntu linux (assuming that you are running Ubuntu) following these steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer

All this of course requires that you open up at least one of your instances to the world.  (Amazon allows to add a public IP to your EC2 instances in a VPC)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. Unfortunately, however, I need to use Windows as the server OS (Windows Server 2008 or 2012).